# How do I exclude multiple elements in a vector by position?

Tags: r, vector

I want to pick elements from a vector and exclude 3 values by what position they got.

I know about the x[-n] function to exclude a single value but I don´t know how to exclude more than one.

Comment: When I tried this I got a warning `Error: `vec_ptype2.integer.logical()` is implemented at C level.
This R function is purely indicative and should never be called.`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use the `c` function to combine the values into a vector:

```
a <- 1:10
a[-c(1,2,3)]
[1]  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```